# Making expandable fixed footer in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble with my bootstrap styling.
I have footer and  the  cols are  col-md -3,3,2,4
This makes the total 12.

The problem is that the contents of each columns  differs, my intention is to put equal spacing between each Div in the col.

How  will i accomplish this?  How can i at least have some  space between latest news and quick links

[image: Footer]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a different diff in your news column that limits it to using only 80% of the available width. Ensuring you always have at least part of the column left over as spacing.

E.g.

```
<div class="row">
    ...
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div style="width:80%">[content]</div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

You should probably give the inner column a class instead of the style to make it cleaner.

**Alternative**

Actually, it's likely easier to just give your column(s) a `padding-right: 20%`.